# Php Carbon: every monday and tuesday every 2 weeks

Tags: php, php-carbon

I can get every monday and tuesday but every weeks

How can I get to every 2 weeks

```
$days = [1,2];
$filterDayOfWeek = function ($date) use ($days) {
        return in_array($date->dayOfWeekIso, $days, true);
};

$period = Carbon::parse($this->entry_start->toDateString())->daysUntil(
        $this->periodicity_end->toDateString()
    );
$period->addFilter($filterDayOfWeek);
```

I saw in the documentation this:

```
 $interval = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::weeks(2);
```

But I don't know how to apply to my perdiod

Thank you

Comment: I don't think an interval will help here. Instead, see if the week of the year number is divisible by 2.

Comment: Yes I have think about that, but in my application it can be every 3, 4, 5 weeks...

Comment: You can use the same logic, just change the modulus number. `$date->weekOfYear % 4 == 0`

Comment: We need precisions: for example if entry_start is Tuesday, will the skipped weeks be between Monday and Tuesday, or will they stick together. What can contain entry_start and how to determine the first date? What can contains $days? Please some examples, so we could give you solution that fit your use case.

Comment: Question: Why `Carbon::parse($this->entry_start->toDateString())` since `$this->entry_start` is already a Carbon instance?

Comment: here is an example

I want Wednesday and Thursday
my start date is a monday
I want Wednesday and Thursday of the same week

If my departure date is a Wednesday, I do not keep this Wednesday, but the next day is a Thursday I keep it

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
function forEveryWeek(Periodicity $periodicity): CarbonPeriod
{
    /**
     * monday, tuesday, wednesday
     * @example : [1,2,3]
     */
    $days = $periodicity->getDays();
    /**
     * @example 1 for every weeks, 2 every 2 weeks, 3,4...
     */
    $repeat_week = $periodicity->getRepeatWeek();

    /**
     * filter days of the week
     * @param $date
     * @return bool
     */
    $filterDayOfWeek = function ($date) use ($days) {
        return in_array($date->dayOfWeekIso, $days, true);
    };

    /**
     * Carbon::class
     * $this->entry_start
     * $this->periodicity_end
     */
    $period = Carbon::parse($this->entry_start->toDateString())->daysUntil(
        $this->periodicity_end->toDateString()
    );

    /**
     * filter every x weeks
     * @param $date
     * @return bool
     */
    $filterWeek = function ($date) use($repeat_week) {
        return $date->weekOfYear % $repeat_week === 0;
    };

    $period->excludeStartDate();
    $period->addFilter($filterDayOfWeek);

    if ($repeat_week > 1) {
        $period->addFilter($filterWeek);
    }

    return $period;
}
```

Comment: This is outstanding, and exactly what I needed.  Thank you.  I did change the period from a parse to a CarbonPeriod, but both should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In every 2 weeks, you first have to determine how you filter odd/even or from a point of start.

`CarbonInterval::weeks(2)` can be used only if nested iterations: 1 loop for 2-weeks, then a loop for days:

```
$days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday'];
foreach (CarbonPeriod::create($start, CarbonInterval::weeks(2), $end, CarbonPeriod::IMMUTABLE) as $baseDate) {
  foreach ($days as $dayName) {
    $date = $baseDate->is($dayName) ? $baseDate : $baseDate->next($dayName);
    echo $date;
  }
}
```

See my comment, if you can give more precision. I can take it into account in the answer.